# How to set search paths allow lua addins as packages

Tags: lua, luabind, module-search-path

**tl;dr:** I want to create lua packages with a custom directory name pattern, having problem with search paths.

**The problem**

I've got an application that I'm wanted to allow the user to write plugins for, following a similar model to Lightroom:

- A default set of plugins are stored in `<app data>/plugins/<name>.myplugin`
- `<name>.myplugin` is a directory bundle which may contain a set of scripts, binaries or other resources
- A plugin may export many different functions to the app, via different scripts
- The names of the exported functions are listed in an `info.lua` file that is read by the app

The problem I'm grappling with is how best to wrap the plugins as packages (modules + submodules) or regular scripts. I envisage that a plugin might include 3rd party modules:

```
Foo.myplugin/
    info.lua - returns a table with plugin name, version info, list of exported functions, etc
    Foo.lua - defines the main functions exported by this plugin, which calls other scripts:
    UsefulFunctions.lua - used by Foo.lua
    3rdparty/3rdparty.lua - 3rd party module
```

If I set the package search path, `package.path` to include

```
<appdata>/?.myplugin/?.lua
```

then I can load the package with `Foo=require 'Foo'`.  However, I can't work out how to get submodules loaded. If `Foo.lua` calls `UsefulFunctions=require 'UsefulFunctions'` then this load fails because lua's search path tries to look for `UsefulFunctions.myplugin/UsefulFunctions.lua`. I can't load it with `require 'Foo.UsefulFunctions'` either, for similar reasons.

Some options:

- One workaround would be to explicitly add each plugin's path to the package path, but this would cause problems if two plugins each contained a submodule of the same name.
- Another option is to write the plugins to use regular lua scripts rather than providing modules, but this still means that the search paths have to be set up inside each plugin.
- A fallback option could be to lose the `.myplugin` suffix which would simplify the package search path.
- Patch Lua to explicitly support this type of search path

Is there any way of providing the functionality I need?

I'm currently on Lua 5.1. I know 5.2 has more control over package search paths, but I don't think I have the option of updating to it at the moment. I'm also using luabind, though I don't think it is relevant to this.

Comment: Why is the `.myplugin` suffix so important in your setup?

Comment: The convenience of being able to identify it as a bundle directory. On mac, by having it as a bundle it appears as a single entity in the Finder.  Lightroom uses `.lrplugin`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how it works on Mac, but how the OS discovers that a directory is a bundle? It is the presence of that specific suffix in its name or you have to set it up in another way? Couldn't you add another level of directories for bundles such as: `<app data>/plugins/bundles/<name>` and tell the OS to treat all the subdirs under `bundles` as bundles?

Comment: There are a few ways, but it's generally done by suffix: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could customize the way Lua searches for modules using a custom searcher function, using the mechanisms outlined in the [documentation of `require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) and [`package.loaders`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders).

The trick is to detect that the module can be found in a directory with the `.myplugins` suffix and to keep track of the path of the bundles. Consider the following scripts.

```
-- <appdata>/plugins/foo.myplugin/foo.lua

local auxlib = require 'foo.auxlib'
local M = {}
function M.Foobnicator()
    print "Called: Foobnicator!!"
    auxlib.AuxFunction()
end
return M
```

```
-- <appdata>/plugins/foo.myplugin/auxlib.lua

local M = {}
function M.AuxFunction()
    print "Called: AuxFunction!!"
end
return M
```

```
-- main.lua

package.path = package.path .. ";" 
    .. [[<appdata>/plugins/?.myplugin/?.lua]]
local bundles = {}  -- holds bundle names and pathnames

local function custom_searcher( module_name )
    if string.match( module_name, '%.' ) then
        -- module name has a dot in it - it is a submodule, 
        -- let's check if it is inside a bundle
        local main_module_name, subname = 
            string.match( module_name, '^([^.]-)%.(.+)' )
        local main_path = bundles[ main_module_name ]
        if main_path then  -- OK, it's a submodule of a known bundle
            local sub_fname = string.gsub( subname, '%.', '/' )
            -- replace main module filename with that of submodule
            local path = string.match( main_path, '^.*[/\\]' ) 
                .. sub_fname .. '.lua'
            return loadfile( path )
        else    -- not a bundle - give up the search
            return
        end
    end

    -- search for the module scanning package.path
    for template in string.gmatch( package.path, '[^;]+' ) do
        if string.match( template, '%.myplugin' ) then -- bundle?                
            local module_path = 
                string.gsub( template, '%?', module_name )
            local fh = io.open( module_path )     -- file exists?
            if fh then  -- module found
                fh:close()
                bundles[ module_name ] = module_path
                return loadfile( module_path )
            end
        end
    end
end

-- sets the custom searcher as the first one so to take
-- precedence over default ones
table.insert( package.loaders, 1, custom_searcher )

local foo = require 'foo'
foo.Foobnicator()
```

Running `main.lua` will produce the following output:

```
Called: Foobnicator!!
Called: AuxFunction!!
```

I hope this will put you on the right track. Probably it doesn't cover every possibility and the error handling is not at all complete, but it should give you a good base to work on.

Comment: Thanks, looks like an interesting approach. One downside though is that you wouldn't want to have this logic in every plugin (a user creating a plugin shouldn't need to care about this). But I guess this same logic could be moved elsewhere and called when initialising each plugin?

Comment: This logic can, and should, be put in some initialization code for the whole application. Once the custom searcher is in place it changes the behavior of `require` globally. Thus it will work also for a `foo2` plug-in, provided it is stored in `<appdata>/plugins/foo2.myplugin`. Changing the logic inside the searcher you could devise more complicated schemes, should the need arise.